# Непонятное поведение LESS2CSS в Sublime Text 3 (less2css error: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл)

Tags: css, node.js, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, less

Приветствую товарищи.
Занялся освоением LESS и не очень удачно...
Сделал все, как тут описано - http://rightblog.ru/2773
Проблема возникла в LESS2CSS

```
[less2css] Using minifier : --clean-css
[less2css] Using verbose mode
[less2css] Converting C:\web-test\test-less\styles\style.less to C:\web-test\test-less\styles\style.css
error: less2css error: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Чего я только не шаманил с настройками, и как только в бубен не бил, не хочет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [баг-трекере LESS2CSS](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css/issues/51) написано следующее:

1. Проверьте путь к less файлу (у вас вроде как корректный)
2. После назначения путей надо перезагрузить Sublime.
3. Некоторым также помогала перезагрузка Windows (скорее всего, это все тот же пункт 2).

В общем, как что-то поменяли с путями (к файлу less, к less.js и т.д.) - надо перегружать Sublime. Попробуйте.

Comment: Класс))) большое спасибо)

Comment: А не подскажете как настроить "less-plugin-autoprefix", что бы он к более ранним браузерам префиксы выдавал?

Comment: Какой именно из less-plugin-autoprefix - их несколько штук разных? В целом лучше переходите на SASS, он становится все популярнее, а LESS все менее.

Comment: нашел))) "Roaming\npm\node_modules\less-plugin-autoprefix\node_modules\browserslist\index.js", тут все было)))

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогла эта [статья](https://myinfo-bissnes.ru/oshibka-less2css-error-winerror-2/).
Я пробовал менять path, сто раз перезагрузил sublime, но благодаря этой статье у меня всё же получилось одолеть sublime.
Достаточно было в cmd установить два плагина и всё!

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка появляется, если вы не указали путь к less.js-windows от Lessc

нужно скачать Lessc c [GitHub](https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows) 
распаковать в любую папку, добавить эту папку в переменную окружения Path.
после этого обязательно перезапустить Sublime.